# Space Optimised query runs slower than expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains day level data. something like below

```
CREATE TABLE test  
(
    id_A INTEGER, -- from 1 to 1k
    id_B INTEGER, -- from 1 to 1k
    nu_B DOUBLE PRECISION,  -- b/w 1 to 8 
    dt_date DATE -- date of activity
);
```

While trying to optimise the performance of a select query on this table 
(let's call it **aggregation_query**)

```
SELECT id_A, dt_date, count(*), sum(nu_B), count(DISTINCT (id_A, dt_date)) 
FROM test
GROUP BY id_A, dt_date;
```

I observed a pattern which helped in reducing the size of the table. It is that, in a given month for one or more days had same values for id_A, id_B and nu_B.

for e.g.

```
id_A, id_B, nu_B, dt_date
23, 24, 5, 2019-12-12
23, 24, 5, 2019-12-15
23, 24, 5, 2019-12-18
29, 27, 2, 2019-12-03 
29, 27, 2, 2019-12-09 
29, 27, 2, 2019-12-11 
29, 27, 2, 2019-12-29
```

Which can be simplified using bitwise representation for days in a month and storing only month for such repeated activities and storing days in which activity actually occurred by using an integer(by setting the bit on days when activities in the month occurred) for e.g. after compression above table will look like below

```
id_A, id_B, nu_B, dt_month, bit_days
23,  24,   5,  2019-12-01,   149504     #000000000000010100100000000000
29,  27,   2,  2019-12-01,   268436740  #0010000000000000000010100000100
```

with this approach we were able to achieve around 50-55% reduction in size of the table and data stored in this compressed format can be expanded by applying a join with a series of 1-31 ints and then checking for which day activity actually made or not. something like below query-:

```
SELECT  *, (dt_month + INTERVAL '1 day' * a.n)::DATE as dt_date
FROM test_compressed tc 
INNER JOIN generate_series(1, 31) a(n) ON (tc.nu_bit_days & (1 << a.n)) > 0
```

but when we tried rewriting above **aggregation_query** select query using this table it started taking 3 times more time than the original query where it was expected to take less time due to reduction in overall space of the table.

here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3994f) to quickly test it. I checked the query plans in both cases but i am not getting much clues in why second query is slower than it's previous counterpart.

Could you please check and suggest what's going wrong here? And is there a way to make it faster than previous one?

Thanks in advance!

Edit1: Somehow queries are not coming properly in sqlfiddle so providing them here.

You can build schema with-:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test 
(
    id_A INTEGER, -- from 1 to 1k
    id_B INTEGER, -- from 1 to 1k
    nu_B DOUBLE PRECISION,  -- num b/w 1 to 8 
    dt_date DATE -- date of activity
);

INSERT INTO test (id_A, id_B, nu_B, dt_date)
  SELECT greatest(1, random()*50)::INT, -- select a num b/w 1 and 100
    greatest(1, random()*50)::INT,   -- select a num between 1 and 100
    (greatest(1, round(8*random()) )),  -- select a num between 1 and 20
    now()::DATE - (a.n%500)   -- assign a date as per loop counter module within last 500 days
  FROM generate_series(1, 500000) as a(n);


 drop table if EXISTS test_compressed;

SELECT
    id_A,
    id_B,
    nu_B,
    date_trunc('month', dt_date) :: DATE as dt_month,
    sum( DISTINCT (1 << (date_part('day', dt_date)::INT) -1) ) as nu_bit_days 
INTO 
    test_compressed
FROM 
    test
GROUP BY 
    id_A, id_B, nu_B, date_trunc('month', dt_date) :: DATE ;
```

Then perform these queries as test to verify the timings.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test; 
SELECT count(*) from test_compressed;

EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT id_A, dt_date, count(*), sum(nu_B), count(DISTINCT (id_A, dt_date)) from test
GROUP BY id_A, dt_date;

EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT id_A, dt_date, count(*), sum(nu_B), count(DISTINCT (id_A, dt_date))
FROM (SELECT  *, (dt_month + INTERVAL '1 day' * a.n)::DATE as dt_date
      FROM test_compressed tc INNER JOIN generate_series(1, 31) a(n)
          ON (tc.nu_bit_days & (1 << a.n)) > 0) as V1
GROUP BY id_A, dt_date;;
```

Comment: what happens if you add an index on `id_A, dt_date` in your test table? My >>assumption<< here is that your generated query is not taking advantage of the reduction of rows due the fact you are joining it with a non indexed "table" (generate series) and performing the bitwise operation on it row by row.

Comment: Your 1st query simply aggregates the data (and could be indexed). But your 2nd query needs an extra step to calculate the same uncompressed data before aggregating it, why do you think this should be faster?

Comment: What happens if you add the index: `create index ix1 on test (id_a, dt_date, id_b, nu_b)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added "VACUUM ANALYZE" at the end of the schema build script. Then, in this query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id_A, dt_date, count(*), sum(nu_B), 
    count(DISTINCT (id_A, dt_date)) from test
GROUP BY id_A, dt_date;
```

The `GROUP BY id_A, dt_date` implies that `count(DISTINCT (id_A, dt_date))` will always be 1 , so I will remove it from the query. Now, let's try...

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx_1 ON test( id_a, dt_date, nu_B );
```

This enables an index-only scan on your large table test and speeds up the query (but it does not answer your question, and it will use disk space for the index, so if you want to compress the table to use less disk space, maybe not such a good idea).

A simple way would be to create a materialized view and summarize all past data by months, including the sum(). However that still doesn't compress the table, and if your your question is a simplified version of your real table and that wouldn't work, so let's move on...

I modified the schema creation script to use 100k rows instead of 500k because sqlfiddle doesn't want to run long queries.

```
SELECT sum(nu_b) FROM test;
```

I just ran that to check how long it takes to scan the table: 14ms. Ideally we want the compressed table to be uncompressed and scanned in a similar time, probably slower but not too much. Let's try it.

```
SELECT sum(nu_b) FROM (
  SELECT  *, (dt_month + INTERVAL '1 day' * a.n)::DATE as dt_date
  FROM test_compressed tc INNER JOIN generate_series(1, 31) a(n)
      ON (tc.nu_bit_days & (1 << a.n)) > 0) as V1;
```

500ms, much slower! That's a problem.

Another problem is it doesn't give the same result, which means either the query or the data is wrong. This is due to the fact that **the data in "test" contains duplicate rows for the same (id_a, id_b, nu_b, dt_date)** which are compressed into a single bit and therefore the duplicate information is lost. So I modified the schema script to remove duplicates.

This means I'll try to **replace the bitfield with an array**, which would work with duplicates if you require them. The bitfield column in the compressed table is replaced by:

```
array_agg( DISTINCT ( date_part('day', dt_date)::SMALLINT) ) as nu_days
```

Then I'll time how long it takes to unpack the table, again by wrapping an aggregate around it...

```
select sum(nu_b) from (
SELECT id_a, id_b, nu_b, dt_month, unnest( nu_days ) as nu_days
  FROM test_compressed_inta )
```

55ms, that's 10x faster than the previous bitfield solution. Note the set-returning function unnest() does all the job.

Unpacking the bitfield compressed table can be done with two methods:

```
SELECT  id_a, id_b, nu_b, dt_month, a.n as nu_days
FROM test_compressed tc INNER JOIN generate_series(1, 31) a(n)
ON (tc.nu_bit_days & (1 << (a.n-1))) > 0 )
```

Note "a.n-1" fixes the off by 1 error in the original query. Or:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id_a, id_b, nu_b, dt_month, generate_series( 1,32 ) as nu_days
  FROM test_compressed ) q1
WHERE nu_bit_days & (1 << (nu_days-1))::INT > 0
```

In this case a row has to be generated and filtered out for every day of the month, whereas the array already contains the desired result. So this method is much slower (about 10x) if few days in each month contain data for each (id_a, id_b, nu_b, dt_month). If months were pretty "full" it would be less of a problem. Table size is a compromise in the opposite direction, as storing long arrays containing many day numbers would take more space than a bitfield. You can investigate using pg_relation_size() on your actual data.

If you want the bitfield to be as fast as the array you'd need a fast set returning function similar to unnest() which returns the positions of bits set to 1. I'm going to keep the array for now.

Now this was only about uncompressing the table. This does not cover your aggregate query.

The problem with your aggregate query is that it generates a full sort then a GroupAggregate (check EXPLAIN ANALYZE results). In the original table this can be avoided with an index-only scan, but this is not possible to do on the compressed table, since the day of month is included in the GROUP BY (and thus in the sort).

Fortunately increasing work_mem to 32 megabytes persuades Postgres to use a hash aggregate instead of a sort. This is okay, there aren't that many buckets with 1k id_a and a date.

```
SELECT id_A, dt_month, nu_days, count(*) c, sum(nu_B) b FROM (
SELECT id_a, id_b, nu_b, dt_month, unnest( nu_days ) as nu_days
  FROM test_compressed_inta ) q1
GROUP BY id_A, dt_month, nu_days;

Original table using index-only scan      55ms
Arrays, with hash (high work_mem)       ~100ms
Arrays, with sort (low work_mem)        ~300ms
```

The bit-field is slower, using the above query to unpack it, it takes 600-700ms, most of which are spent generating rows for each day and filtering them out...

Note I removed `(dt_month + INTERVAL '1 day' * a.n)::DATE as dt_date` from the inner loop as it is faster to aggregate on (dt_month,nu_days) then to rebuild the date afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot @peufeu for taking a look at my question!